# linking libraries in qt creator for c++ project

Tags: qt-creator

I am creating normal c++ project using QT creator . 
I need to link the boost library. I have used this in eclipse project under Project Properties/C C++ build/Gcc C++ linker/-l boost_filesystem  but i am not sure how to do it in QT creator.

Answer (score 0):

I use Qt, but not Qt-Creator so I'm not sure where in it's UI you might do this.

But in the .pro file (the input to the makefile), you would specify the library with:

```
LIBS += -lboost_filesystem  # assuming 'boost_filesystem' is the name of the lib file
LIBS += -L/[wherever boost lib files are on your system]
```

"-l" is the file name and "-L" is the library path name.

```
LIBS += -lboost_filesystem -L/[wherever boost lib files are on your system]
```

works too.

"+=" appends it to the current QMake variables, be careful about using "=", unless you really intend to replace the values.

Comment: i use a normal c++ project so there wont be .pro file

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if this is still an issue for you, but I answer because it may help some others like me who had a similar issue.

As far as I understood it: When you use QtCreator with normal C++ you will be asked which build tool to use. I have chosen CMake, so from now on everything goes via CMake and less things go directly via QtCreator. That's the reason that there is no .pro file anymore.

So what I did to resolve the issue was to add following line after the `add_executable(...)` line in the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
target_link_libraries(my_project_name -lboost_system)
```

Note: I just needed lboost_system, but I think that just expanding the list with `-lboost_filesystem` etc.. will do the job.

Hope that it helps somebody.